# Using Javascript to prevent form submission if select fields are the same?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have five select boxes in HTML. I have to make sure that when the form is submitted these values aren't the same - they all need to be different. I have a Javascript script that gets each value by doing this:

```
var rankCheck = document.getElementById("rank1");
var rankChoice = rankCheck.options[rankCheck.selectedIndex].value;
```

This should store whatever value the user chose while filling out the script into the variable rankChoice. Since I have five select boxes, I take the first select box and ensure that this box does not have the same value as the others. However I'm having a hard time getting this to stop the form submission - when I did some required fields with Javascript it worked just fine but even when I give an alert and return false, the form seems to submit anyway.

Here is a select box example:

```
              Item:
                    <select id="rank1" name="rank" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
```

The comparison works like so:

```
if(rank1 != rank2 && rank1 != rank3 && rank1 != rank4 && rank1 != rank5) {
    return true;
}
else {
    alert'Some alert') ;
    return false;
}
```

Should I be calling this function onSubmit or onClick? Also, should I call it when the user clicks the form submit button or interacts with the last selection? I saw a few threads saying to redirect back to the page, but I'd like to just prevent submission if possible.

Comment: Have you tried the `preventDefault` of the submit event? Like: `$('#form').submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();`

Comment: @LcSalazar Nope, haven't tried that yet. How would it be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

call function onclick() and submit with
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
if true else give error!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the second part? Should I call the function onClick() and place it in my submit button input tag?

Comment: like:<form id="myForm">...... <input type="button" onclick="func();" name="submit" value="submit"/> <form/>  and in func(){ ...... document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); }

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest some jQuery.  Specifically jQuery validate.  You can add a custom method to jQuery validator to check that your fields aren't equal using the add method function:

jQuery.validator.addMethod

jQuery validate will also run as the user enters data into the fields which will allow them to see if there is an error condition before submission.

Here is the jQuery validation link:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

and the link to the addMethod function: 
http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/